# live status of trains using google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am planning to develop a android app which get the live status of trains
by passing source and destination by using google maps direction API.Please suggest me how can I do that.

Comment: what exactly you want suggestion with? your task includes numerous subtasks. Which one is a problem?

Comment: @VladMatvienko When we enter our source and destination in Google map and select transit mode Google map display information(actual arrival,train number,etc) regarding available trains from source to destination, so how can I fetch that same data using their api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to use Indian railway api.. 
and that api have some limitations like. And you need an API key which you have to get from indian railway. and request must be done from server not mobile app. some of limitations are

> Requests should be made from your server only and not from the clients
>   browser or app.
>
> API key is applicable for requests from one IP only
>
> Developers should cache the data on their server, following limits
>   apply while making requests between 00:00hr to 23:59 hrs IST
>
> - GetStations 10
> - GetTrains between unique pair of stations 4
> - Max 5 requests per second

Comment: I have tried railway api but it becomes unresponsive at a time and it doesn't shows data of many places

Comment: Have you get API key ??

Comment: yaa I have used this website http://www.railwayapi.com to get APi key

Comment: you can check this link api.erail.in

Comment: they have stopped giving Api key